# MatLab updating a recursive variable.

Tags: matlab

See the code

```
x(1) = 0;
k = 1;
   while x(k) <=6

   x(k) = x(k) +2

    k = k +1;

end
```

So I want the code to output

> x(1) = 2
>
> x(2) = 4
>
> x(3) = 6

Basically I want to write out a list of x(i)s, that gets updated during each iteration. But I am getting an "out of bound" error and I realize that there is a conflict with the way MatLab sees "()" as a vector.

Anyway to get around this?

**EDIT1**

What if I want to do

```
x = 0;
y = 0;
k = 1;
   while x <=6 && y<=13

   x = x +2;
   y = y + 3 +x;

    k = k +1;

end
```

I want this to output

> x = 2
>
> y = 5
>
> x = 4
>
> y = 8

But it's not doing that, and I don't want to do this in two separate scripts. I want to handle everything at once.

Comment: Print Step #$k$ and then $x = ?$.

Comment: @JohnHabert, wait what?

Comment: Skip trying to label your variable recursively. Just print the step number and the answer for that step. You are already counting what step you are at with $k$.

Comment: You mean just have $x(k) + 2$ instead of $x(k)  = x(k) +2$? I still get errors

Comment: I'm saying just do $x = x+2$; and for output generate something that looks like:  Step #1 : x = 2, Step #2 : x = 4, etc.

Comment: Huh, interesting. What happens if I want to do this recursively (no more updating), that is x(k+1) = x(k) +2?

Comment: You would need to define a function and do recursion that way.

Comment: I just tried out my own method and it kind of works, but I am getting extra information (I actually don't know what they are)

Comment: Sorry is there a way to do this with more than one variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your code, in the line

```
x(k)=x(k) + 2
```

because x(k) is not yet defined. See the correct code:

```
x(1) = 0;
k = 1;
   while x(k) <=6

   x(k+1) = x(k) +2

    k = k +1;

end
```

Comment: What if I want to update two variables at once?

Comment: Provide an example.

Comment: See edit post please